# JUnit how set up test class?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, kotlin

I use constructor of test class for mocking objects. But I want to set parameters for stubs mocking objects from each test methods.
I tried using constructors parameters of test class, but JUnit limiting this:

```
java.lang.Exception: Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor
```

What I should use for this purpose?

Now I use different class for store mocks and it not looks nicely

```
package testci

import org.junit.Test
import org.mockito.Mockito.*

interface Object {
    fun get(p: Int): Int
}

class setUpMock(val param: Int, val param2: Int) {
    val mock = mock(Object::class.java)!!
    init {
        `when`(mock.get(param)).thenReturn(param2)
    }
}

class HelloTest {
    @Test
    fun `first test`() {
        val sMock = setUpMock(1,2)
        println(sMock.mock.get(1))
    }

    @Test
    fun `second test`() {
        val sMock = setUpMock(1,3)
        println(sMock.mock.get(1))
        verify(sMock.mock).get(1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default JUnit 4 runner doesn't provide such a feature : [parameterized tests](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/parameterized-tests).
To use it, you need to annotate your class with the `Parameterized` runner class and to define a `@Parameterized.Parameters` function that sets the parameter values for each scenario.

For example :

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

@RunWith(Parameterized::class)
class HelloTest(val param1: Int, val param2: Int) {

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @Parameterized.Parameters
        fun data() = listOf(
                arrayOf(1, 2),
                arrayOf(1, 3)
        )
    }
    @Test
    fun `first test`() {
        val sMock = setUpMock(param1, param2)
        println(sMock.mock.get(1))
    }

    @Test
    fun `second test`() {
        val sMock = setUpMock(param1, param2)
        println(sMock.mock.get(1))
        verify(sMock.mock).get(1)
    }
}
```

No tested code but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

With Junit5 you can achieve it without extra class.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.CsvSource
import org.mockito.Mockito.*
import kotlin.test.assertEquals

interface Object {
    fun get(p: Int): Int
}

class HelloTest {

    var mock = mock(Object::class.java)!!

    @Test
    fun `first test`() {
        `when`(mock.get(1)).thenReturn(2)
        assertEquals(2, mock.get(1))
    }

    @Test
    fun `second test`() {
        `when`(mock.get(1)).thenReturn(2)
        println(mock.get(1))
        verify(mock).get(1)
    }

    @CsvSource("1,2","3,4")
    @ParameterizedTest
    fun `csv parameterized test`(key: Int, value: Int){
        `when`(mock.get(key)).thenReturn(value)
        assertEquals(value, mock.get(key))
    }
}
```

Note `@CsvSource` for parameterized tests. There are several ways of [writing parameterized tests with junit5.](https://blog.codefx.org/libraries/junit-5-parameterized-tests/#Ins-And-Outs-of-Parameterized-Tests) Following dependencies are required.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-test-junit</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```